# How to include a dropdown menu and a table in a form using php, mysql and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, database-connection

I am trying to make a HTML form that includes a dropdown menu and a "normal" table form where user can enter values from keyboard. I want to populate the dropdown menu with info from MySQL database.

This is my code, but the webpage has a little dropdown menu, but when I click the down arrow, there are no options to choose from. My code is below, could anyone please help?

```html
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
$result = mysqli_query($sqlQuery);
?>

<form method = "post" action = "webpage.php">
    <?php
    echo '<select name = "select">';
    while($sqlRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $row = $sqlRow['attribute'];
       echo '<option value="'.$row.'">' .$row. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>

    <table>
      <tr><td> Field1 </td><td> <input type="text" name="field1">         </td></tr>
      <tr><td> Field2 </td><td><input type = "text" name = "field2">       </td></tr>   
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" value ="Submit" name="sendIt">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a database connection as parameter 1 of the query, e.g. `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);` instead of `mysqli_query($sqlQuery);`.

For setting up such a connection in this case, see for example **Example (MySQLi Procedural)** at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Otherwise when you run into such problems you need to turn on errors display, say with the following kind of code put at the top of the php page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This would enable you to see the errors and track them down.